# How to Fit the Downloaded Images into the ImageView (to Eliminate the Need for Scrolling)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-resources

My app gets the album cover images from an Internet source. The image dimensions are varying from 200*200 to 400*400, therefore making scrolling necessary on some smaller devices. The layout resource codes and layout view are below.

The ImageView is the view with the red borders.

All I need is to make downloaded image to fit the imageView, so that the users won't have to scroll vertically to see the view below. How can I accomplish that? Thanks in advance...

[image: Sample image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llayoutAlbumCover"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top|center" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/albumCover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3sp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/loading" >
        </ImageView>

    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think   `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`  is best when we do not have a fix size image.It places images accordingly with your imagesview..

Comment: @Mohit, unfortunately, centerCrop does not work

Answer (score 0):

use `imgview.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);`

Through xml also you use like this

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/albumCover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3sp"
             android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/loading" >
        </ImageView>
```

PS:: I know this is what you wanted, but for images where you care about aspect ratio, this will stretch it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set scale, for example `imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.fitCenter)`
Samples: http://etcodehome.blogspot.com/2011/05/android-imageview-scaletype-samples.html

Answer (score 0):

Using `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` guarantees at least one axis will be fitted in the view. Use `android:scaleType="centerInside"` instead. The dimensions will be equal or smaller then your view. For more options please check [ImageView.ScaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: Just to be sure, you are not using `ImageView.setBackground(Drawable background)` to set the image right?

Comment: I am using: mImageViewAlbumCover.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

Comment: I'm afraid you should post some results regarding the scaleType change. What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Nothing happened? Or something happened but not what you expect?